# Accessing Site with a WWW prefix results in a 500 internal server error!

Tags: linux, centos, .htaccess, 500-error

I have migrated to a new server and when ever I try to use my site with the www prefix I get a 500 internal server error. This use to work on my previous host just fine. Here is a snippet of the htaccess file which refers to the www - no where else does it refer to the www.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /search.php?searchfor=$1&sortby=$2&page=$3&searchterm=$4
RewriteRule ^confirmemail/(.*) /confirmemail.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^resetpassword/(.*) /resetpassword.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^resendconfirmation/(.*) /resendconfirmation.php?userid=$1
RewriteRule ^categories/ /categories.php
RewriteRule ^([-_~*a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\/)?$ /memberprofile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^browse/audios/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /audios.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4
RewriteRule ^browse/categories/audios/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /categoryaudios.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4
RewriteRule ^audios/(.*)/(.*) /playaudio.php?audioid=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule ^download/audio/(.*)/(.*) /downloadaudio.php?AUDIOID=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule ^members/audios/(.*)/(.*) /memberaudios.php?pid=$1&username=$2
RewriteRule ^syndicate/audios/(.*)/(.*) /syndicateaudios.php?filter=$1&title=$2
</IfModule>
```

What else can I check?

I have setup this domain up with Plesk Control Panel - maybe this is the issue?

Thanks all for any help

### Update

The error logs show this when i go to my site using the www prefix.

> [Wed Sep 08 13:57:24 2010] [error]
>   [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx] Request
>   exceeded the limit of 10 internal
>   redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase
>   the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel
>   debug' to get a backtrace.

### Update 2

My site has a server alias in the httpd.conf file **of the form** `serverAlias www.mydomain.com` - can this cause redirect loop?

### Update 3

I was not able to get apache to create or write to the rewrite log and I don't want to do too many service restarts since there are people using the site.

I have added a bounty to this question as I really need help!

Comment: Do you have an error message, not just the error code?

Comment: Check your Apache httpd's `ErrorLog` for the domain.

Comment: @Christian - The message is "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: @joschi - I have updated my question with the error that is shown.

Comment: Use `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` to see which redirections occur on your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting because the logs state that a redirect is happening, but you do not have any rules which use the [R] flag. However, when a rule includes http://... the [R] flag is redundant, so the

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1
```

rule is the likely candidate for causing the problem.

**If I were you, I would try putting [R=301,L] at the end of that line to make sure the other rules aren't somehow using the previous host name, somehow resulting in a loop.**

Another possibility is that PHP is involved in the redirect loop. Can you access the www site with Firefox and the livehttpheaders plugin, and share the headers here? That may shed some light on what is causing the redirect loop.

I do not think that the fact that Plesk is involved has anything to do with it, and no, I don't think the ServerAlias has anything to do with it. That only allows the same configuration to be served for both virtual hosts: www.example.com and example.com.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You sir, are what we call a genius! :) That worked perfectly! Thank you so much, this saved me!...Bounty will be awarded in 22 hours...

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the http://=[R] bit, thats damn handy to know!

Comment: Glad I helped! I <3 mod_rewrite. Ralf S. Engelschall rocks!

Answer (score 0):

There's also a [rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog), activate it and see what happens.

For most of cases it is a reentrant rule.

Comment: This is strange - I have enabled this for my domain, however nothing appears in that log. Maybe I need to do something different in Plesk. I have restarted apache btw.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1
...
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Will this cause problems with subdomains?

Comment: The `RewriteCond` only works on the first `RewriteRule` immediately after it. We are saying here, if the host does not start with mydomain, redirect it. So maybe.. your question didn't mention subdomains.